# Static methods from abstract class

Tags: c#

I know similar questions have been asked often enough on here but I've been searching for a while for something that deals with the issue I'm having.

I'm building an application and had three separate classes for 'Team', 'Manager' and 'Employee'. I realised that I was repeating a lot of code for all three so I defined an abstract class called 'Worker'.

On each of the classes I've defined a `GetAllX` method that returns and `IEnumerable<X>`, for example:

```
public static IEnumerable<Manager> GetAllManagers()
{
    //Code to get all managers
    yield return m
    //find next manager and loop
}
```

What I want is to be able to define a method in my abstract class called `GetAll` which will return an IEnumerable of type T where T is the class inheriting from my abstract class. Is there any way to achieve something like this?

Comment: Sometimes I regret that Stack Overflow won't accept "No" as a complete comment.

Comment: Forget about the static nonsense and create abstract `GetAll` and implement it.

Comment: Why would a class named Manager have a method called GetAllMangers? Your are mixing too many things

Comment: You need GetAll() to be an instance method of something. If all instances of `Manager` were stored in an instance of a class called (for example) `InstanceCollector<Manager>`, you could give `Manager` a static singleton instance of `InstanceCollector<Manager>`, and then the singleton instance would have the generic GetAll() method. That's not perfect, but it's cleaner than copy/pasting the entire `GetAll*` method three times.

Comment: Ahh, how annoying. Is there a clever way to do something like this? The thing is that the only difference in code for each of the 'GetAll' functions is really small so I'd like to be able to declare static properties of each class that needs to implement it and have one method that draws on those properties to find all the managers/employees etc.

Comment: GetAll seems like something that should be implemented in the Team class. Team should have a property defined as List<IWorker> Workers or something similar. Implement IWorker on Employee and Manager. That's it.

Comment: I also feel like your inheritance hierarchy is a bit screwy. After all, a manager is still an employee right?

Comment: @sam I've got the in-built collections of sub-ordinates working there are just times that I need to pull through every single worker on the db regardless of their manager

Comment: @DavidG for the purposes of the application, managers aren't employees, their only purpose is to lead a group of employees, and there'll never be another level of the hierarchy as an employee will never lead another employee.

Comment: Can you post some code (even if it doesn't work) that shows all the code elements? Specifically, all the `GetAll*` methods inside proper classes and how you want it to work.

Comment: @Vikhram I would but there's not really any more context I could give, they're pretty skeletal classes right now. The reason I want all the `GetAll` method to be inherited or something similar is because they all rely on queries where only the field names and table names would need changing and all the rest of the code would be the same, I wanted to set each class up with some static variables that would represent those variable parts of the query.

Comment: Is it possible to define a static class with a `GetAll()` method that takes an argument of one of the derived classes, looks at static variables of that class and returns an `IEnumerable` of the same type? Or is it just reaching a silly point where I should leave them as separately defined methods?

Comment: There is lot more worded ambiguously in English in your post, that I would rather see unambiguously in C#. For example `abstract class Worker { IEnumerable<T> GetAll() { // something here } }` and `class Manager : Worker { // some property that you are talking about should come here}`

Comment: Oh aye I don't disagree I haven't come up with good names for my classes yet

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could do

```
abstract class Worker
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : Worker
    {
        //your code
    }
}

class Manager : Worker
{
}

class Employee : Worker
{
}
```

And this method calling `var managers = Worker.GetAll<Manager>();`

---

Another approach using different static variables, what OP wants as described in comment.

```
abstract class Worker<T> where T : Worker<T>
{
    protected static string name;

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
}

class Manager : Worker<Manager>
{
    static Manager()
    {
        name = "Manager";
    }
}

class Employee : Worker<Employee>
{
    static Employee()
    {
        name = "Employee";
    }
}
```

And using

```
//create object to call static constructors
//this need only once for every concrete class
var test = new Manager();
var test1 = new Employee();

var managers = Worker<Manager>.GetAll();
var employees = Worker<Employee>.GetAll();
```

---

Technically, you can do it, but in my opinion, classical repository is approach that is more suitable.

Comment: This is super close! I wanted to be able to define a static variable in each Class that I would need to call `GetAll` of and to be able to use that static variable in query I would run to actually `GetAll` of them. Using this approach I can switch on the `typeof(T)` and it's contained in the worker class which I like, I've ended up just writing a separate static class with three separately named methods as it isn't that much code to replicate. Thanks though!

Comment: "I can switch on the `typeof(T)`" - _Please_ don't do that, that smells like you are not using classes they way you should!